# RESTful URL to check unique username and email address

Tags: api, rest, api-design

During registration I am asking for username, email, and password. I am checking if the username and email is unique via the following end points

```
HEAD /auth/:email
HEAD /users/:username
```

Uniqueness of emails and usernames is split into auth and users resource because I thought when logging in I am asking for email so that should be in the auth and checking if the username is unique or not can go in users.

Login happens at the following endpoint

```
POST /auth/login
```

A new user is created at the following endpoint

```
POST /users
```

This is a stateless API and I am wondering if my routes look RESTful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am wondering if my routes look RESTful?

REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers, so long as they conform to the production rules described in RFC 3986.

See, for instance: [Tilkov 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pspy1H6A3FM).

Instead, you should choose your identifier spelling conventions to make things easier for your human beings: what spellings are easy to document?  what spellings are easy to recognize in the access logs? and so on.

---

You *might* be better off with a single resource that reports the status of the email address and username together, rather than using two different reports to do that.

Similarly, using HEAD requests is a bit *weird*; you are apparently using metadata in the [transfer of documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) domain to communicate your business semantics, which (a) is what the documents are for and (b) is an example of "accidental complexity" -- I won't go so far as to guarantee problems down the road, but you are certainly inviting them, and it's not obvious that the current benefits outweigh that risk.